# Is it possible to use Delphi XE2 to develop Windows CE Applications?

Tags: delphi, windows-ce, delphi-xe2

I have to develop an application to run on Windows CE accessing a remote Firebird database. 
I would like to use Delphi to do so.
Is it possible?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677133.aspx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Native Delphi only works with x86 compatible processors and Win32/Win64 or MacOS 10 API.

Ken White already pointed to you Delphi Prism, however if you would purchase it, instead of re-marked tool, you'd perhaps purchase the original product, i heard it comes with multiple platforms support instead of one. [RemObjects Oxygene](http://www.remobjects.com/oxygene/platforms/) is the original product, part of which is re-sold as Prism.

Another option would be using Lazarus (vanilla or CodeTyphon distro). Its LCL library mimics VCL in many respects and FPC compiler mimics Delphi language (and some other Pascal dialects as well).

- http://www.pilotlogic.com/codetyphon/help/index.html?cross_build_for_windows_mobile.htm
- http://wiki.freepascal.org/Windows_CE_Interface
- http://www.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?topic=8175.0

Answer (score 6):

No, it isn't. Delphi XE2 does apps for Win32/64, OS X, (and with the help of FreePascal, iOS), but not for CE.

You can probably use Delphi Prism to do so. There is a separate `delphi-prism` tag for that here at SO.

Answer (score 5):

In fact, you may be able to use the Delphi IDE to build Windows CE applications, using [KOL-CE](http://wiki.freepascal.org/KOL-CE) library, after some adaptations.

KOL-CE - Key Objects Library CE is a set of objects to develop powerful (but compact) Windows CE/Pocket PC/Windows Mobile/Win32 GUI applications using Free Pascal Compiler. The library is based on KOL library by Vladimir Kladov (http://kolmck.net).

It targets the Lazarus IDE, but since it is a fork of a Delphi project, you may be able to use it in your Delphi IDE, perhaps after some modifications. And if you are not able (or do not have the time) to do the needed modifications, I'm quite confident that you would be pleased to use the Lazarus IDE and modern object pascal instead of switching to another language.

You need to install the FPC arm-wince cross compiler for Win32 to compile WinCE executables, but you develop your application in Windows, with the IDE.

Note that KOL is a light new set of components, very diverse to the VCL. Very powerful, but only low-level object code can be re-used, since they are not compatible with the VCL (or the Lazarus LVCL).

Using Lazarus and its native LVCL components is also available to Windows CE, is much close to the VCL classes layout, but will produce much bigger executables than KOL-CE.

Comment: Doing it with KOL and FPC isn't doing it in XE2, which is what the question directly asked.

Comment: You may be able to use Delphi XE2 as the IDE, then use FPC only to cross-compile to ARM target. This is how KOL-CE works. I wrote that since KOL is now Unicode ready, may be KOL-CE could be adapted to work with Delphi XE2. Perhaps it is already the case, even if Lazarus is the primary IDE now.

Comment: if KOL-CE was designed to mimic KOL, then the same set of MCK should cover both ?

Answer (score 4):

For the historic perspective: no you can't in Delphi itself as of Delphi 2007.

In Delphi 2005 and Delphi 2006 could do this, targeting the .NET Compact Framework on Windows CE as Delphi contained a Delphi .NET compiler that was more compatible with the Delphi language than the current (but much more evolved) Oxygene .NET/Java platform implementation of the Delphi language.

As of Delphi 2007, the Delphi .NET compiler got retired.

Right now, Oxygene is much better as it supports a broader set of language and platform features than Delphi .NET ever did. It is less compatible with the Delphi language because the platforms it supports warranted for some language deviations that in practice are very useful.

Oxygene ships both separately (with a full feature set) and as Delphi Prism (with only the .NET portion).

For Delphi 2005/2006 you needed the [CF Build Helper](http://www.jed-software.com/cf.htm) from Jeremy North and the Class Helpers I wrote (they are included in the CF Build Helper). [A nice article on how to use both is at EDN](https://edn.embarcadero.com/article/33507).

Given the hoopla you had to go through back then, it is much wiser to use Oxygene if you want a language very close to the Delphi language.

For a historic overview of Pascal and Delphi like languages, read [this article by Jim McKeeth](http://www.remobjects.com/oxygene/language/history.aspx).